# Powershell Custom Object toString value is used as a Note Property

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

I'm working with the `JIRA API` with the Issue changelog. The API call returns `JSON` key/value pairs. One of the keys is `toString` which is represented in the PS Custom Object as a `NoteProperty`. (Other keys are "to" "from" "fromString", etc.) When I reference the `toString NoteProperty`, PS thinks I'm calling the `ToString()` string method and it gives an `OverLoadDefinition` error.

`$response` is the variable I use to store the API call output.

```
$response.changelog.histories.items.to            # this works fine
$response.changelog.histories.items.fromString    # this works fine
$response.changelog.histories.items.toString      # This fails.
```

PS thinks I want to call the `toString()` method.

Is there a way to force PS to use the `NoteProperty` value stored in the `toString` key?

Comment: Can you give some code which reproduces this? If I do `$test = "{'items':{'toString':2}}" | ConvertFrom-Json; $test.items.toString` then it returns the value 2. And it shows toString is a NoteProperty on a PSCustomObject.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it into single brakets like this:

```
$response.changelog.histories.items.'toString'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same result - OverloadDefintions.

Answer (score 0):

By trying some options I found something that works:

```
$JiraIssue = "https://jira/rest/api/2/issue/DAA-2662?fields=key,id,reporter&expand=changelog"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $JiraIssue -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $myCreds"} -ContentType application/json

$response.changelog.histories.items.tostring # FAILS

$response.changelog.histories.items[0].tostring  # WORKS
foreach ($i in $response.changelog.histories.items ) {$i.tostring }  # WORKS
```

When I reference items.toString it looks like PS is confused between the toString method and the NoteProperty with the same name. But when I reference a single array value within the items array items[0].toString, PS knows that I want the NoteProperty.

Any further comments or insight on this is most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and found this worked

$response.changelog.histories.items | Select-Object -expand toString